# PHP - UTF8 isn't displayed correctly although everything should be right

Tags: php, utf-8

There's an UTF8 problem on my site which I can't solve (nor understand).
When I use...

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

... on my webspace, then special chars are displayed incorrectly. When I delete this function, then all special chars from database queries are displayed correctly. On my local system it's the opposite (without set_charset('utf8') the chars are not displayed in proper manner)

I also made a test script to see if this is a problem of my webhost. The test works correct on my webspace and locally.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$db = new mysqli( bla bla );
$db->set_charset('utf8');
$sql  = "SELECT pages_title
         FROM pages
         WHERE pages_title = 'Günstige Tablet PCs'";
$result = $db->prepare( $sql );
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result( $title );
$result->store_result();
$result->fetch();
$result->free_result(); 

echo "Title: ". $title;
```

Now I'm running out of ideas where the problem could be. Everything is set right:

1. The database itself is set to utf8-general-ci
2. Files are formatted in UTF8.
3. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` is set.

Because the test script is running correctly the problem should be within my code, but I got no idea what could cause the error, because I'm not doing anything with utf8_encode/decode or something like that.

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: Do the entries in the database show up correctly using, say, phpMyAdmin?

Comment: You should use the `header` function instead of the `meta` element.

Comment: yes, everything is fine there

Comment: @Gumbo `s/instead of/as well as` - you should indeed set the charset in the headers, but you should still declare the encoding in the document.

Comment: Was a header problem, hank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this, should solve it.

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```

Comment: Ok, and did you change the charset in the database you have? I mean when creating the tables. This could possibly be an issue!

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially have problems with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try copy/pasting your entire code to another text editor and saving it as "Unicode without BOM" (say Notepad++).

Comment: Also a good advice, but in this case the files were formatted correctly. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the right headers:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The headers sent by default depend on the server (e.g: apache) configuration -- this may cause confusion in different environments.